# How do I insert data into an existing Excel spreadsheet from data table by mapping Excel sheet column header?

Tags: openxml, epplus

I have macro Excel spreadsheet with column header and some columns are computed columns.

What I need to do is get the data from database and populate this file.

DataTable I retrieved after query does not have all columns as in Excel file as Excel file has computed columns.

So I need to map the column from the data table to Excel file and load the data.
I need to make sure to delete existing data from the file before I load the new data as this file needs to be created every week.

I have never worked in OpenXML Document and EPPlus.

Attempt #1 : using EPPlus

```
private static void OtehrMethod(DataTable dataTable, string filePath)
{
    // using EPPlus
    var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));

    ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        int i = 1;
        object cellValue = workSheet.Cells[2, i].Value;

        workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = Conver.ToInt(row["Id"]);
        // break;
        //workSheet.Cells[2, i].Value =row["First_Name"].ToString();
        //workSheet.Cells[3, i].Value = row["Last_Name"].ToString();
        //workSheet.Cells[4, i].Value = row["Job_Title"].ToString();
        //workSheet.Cells[5, i].Value = row["Skills"].ToString();
        i++;
    }

    package.Save();
}
```

Attempt #2: using Open XML

```
private static void SomeMethod()
{
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"];
    string workingSheetName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkingSheetName"];

    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        // WorkbookPart workbook = document.WorkbookPart;
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        Workbook workbook = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook;

        int sheetIndex = 0;

        foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetpart in workbook.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = worksheetpart.Worksheet;

            string sheetName = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().ElementAt(sheetIndex).Name;

            if (sheetName.ToUpper() == workingSheetName.ToUpper())
            {
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();

                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    // How do I map Excel sheet column with data table column and insert the values into Excel ?

                    // Column["FirstName"] = DTRow["FirstName"]
                    //Column["LastName"] = DTRow["LastName"]
                }
            }

            sheetIndex++;
        }
    }
    // throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, EPPlus is a wrapper around OpenXML. The concepts below would therefore apply to both. The learning curve can be steep so I will start with a Vincent Tan program for you to examine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet;

namespace ExcelOpenXmlSetCellValue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sFile = "ExcelOpenXmlSetCellValue.xlsx";
            if (File.Exists(sFile))
            {
                File.Delete(sFile);
            }
            try
            {
                BuildWorkbook(sFile);
                Console.WriteLine("Program end");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void BuildWorkbook(string filename)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart wbp = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
                WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Workbook wb = new Workbook();
                FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
                fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
                Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sd = new SheetData();

                Row r;
                Cell c;

                r = new Row();
                // For the 2nd row. I know, it's obvious, but it's recommended
                // that you assign a value. While Excel might be able to handle
                // a Row class without the RowIndex assigned (in a certain case),
                // other applications might find that difficult, in particular,
                // your own application.
                r.RowIndex = 2;
                c = new Cell();
                // "D" for 4th column. The "2" is equal to the RowIndex of the Row
                // that the Cell class is in. Note that the number part has to be
                // equal to the RowIndex or disaster will happen. Or worse, Excel
                // spits out the "file corrupted" error and your user sees it.
                c.CellReference = "D2";
                // by default, an unassigned DataType means CellValues.Number
                //c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("9.81");
                r.Append(c);
                sd.Append(r);

                // What if you need more Cell's in a Row? Blank lines added for readability.
                r = new Row();
                r.RowIndex = 5;

                c = new Cell();
                // this way, the number part is always right, but you need to
                // assign the RowIndex first. This will make sense when you have
                // to append many Cell classes. This is just an alternative to
                // assigning the cell reference.
                c.CellReference = "F" + r.RowIndex;
                // There are 2 other string types, the SharedString and InlineString.
                // They are discussed in another chapter. The CellValues.String type
                // provides the most straightforward way of including text strings.
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("Is");
                r.Append(c);

                c = new Cell();
                c.CellReference = "G" + r.RowIndex;
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("that in");
                r.Append(c);

                c = new Cell();
                c.CellReference = "H" + r.RowIndex;
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("metres per second squared?");
                r.Append(c);

                // This is for row 5
                sd.Append(r);

                // And now, to show you sometimes the code can be rearranged a little.
                // But because you need to append the Cell class to the Row class,
                // it makes sense (logically and conceptually) to initialise a new Row first.
                c = new Cell();
                c.CellReference = "F7";
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("It'd better be. Just got used to the metric system.");
                r = new Row();
                r.RowIndex = 7;
                r.Append(c);
                sd.Append(r);

                ws.Append(sd);
                wsp.Worksheet = ws;

                wsp.Worksheet.Save();
                Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
                Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
                sheet.Name = "Sheet1";
                sheet.SheetId = 1;
                sheet.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
                sheets.Append(sheet);
                wb.Append(fv);
                wb.Append(sheets);

                xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
                xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                xl.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then an excerpt from his book may help conceptually:

> So the SheetData class contains Row classes as children. Each Row class contains Cell classes as children. A Row class represents a row
>   in the spreadsheet. A Cell class represents a cell in the spreadsheet.
>   Sometimes, obvious things still need to be said.
>
> It is recommended that you assign a value for the RowIndex property of
>   the Row class. This is basically the row number for that Row class. If
>   it's the 4th row, assign 4. The RowIndex property is optional under
>   Open XML specifications, but spreadsheet applications might not have a
>   way to deal with this. Even Excel handles a blank RowIndex property
>   correctly under special conditions (which we'll talk about later in
>   this chapter).
>
> As for the Cell class, you need to take note of these properties: 
>
> - DataType - The data type of the cell value. You will most probably deal with CellValues.Number and CellValues.String.
> - CellReference - The cell reference in "A1 format". That means the column letter followed by the row index. For example, "C5" means the
>     3rd column, 5th row. There's the "R1C1 format" ("R" then row index,
>     then "C" then column index, giving us "R5C3" for the previous
>     example), but we're not covering that. "A1 format" is the default in
>     Excel.
> - CellValue - Where the action happens. You might notice that CellValue is actually a class, and its main value is a string. This
>     means you store number values in string form too (the DataType
>     property determines the, well, data type).
> - CellFormula - Where you have a cell formula. But you can read about it in another chapter. The above 3 properties are the usual ones to
>     handle.
>
> One more thing. The Row classes must be appended to the SheetData
>   class in ascending RowIndex order. The Cell classes must be appended
>   to its Row class in ascending column order. This is not negotiable.
>   Excel will choke on its error vomit otherwise.

Hopefully, this is enough to get you on track. If not, I'll check back for further questions.

In answer to your other question, for the computed columns, build your calculations on the right hand side for the cell you build for the calculated column.

Comment: I do not want to delete the existing XLSM SpreedSheet. I want to clear the data in the excel sheet or you could say overwrite. It has multiple sheets. 
It is on its own an reporting application and it is quite big. 
Data on the sheet, which I am working on it, feeds the data to other sheets and charts. 
I would like to use this existing file as an template and insert the data so that others computed columns
and other referenced sheets gets the data automatically as soon as the sheet i am working on gets populated.

Answer (score 2):

Much clearer. You are in territory that I have not personally coded in, but the SheetData for each sheet would be where to clear data. Below is another program from Vincent Tan that shows how to add and alter data in existing sheets:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet;

namespace ExcelOpenXmlFromTemplate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Switch between an Excel file with the styles and stuff
            // and an actual Excel template file.
            // I suggest you check out the accompanying template files first
            // to compare how the original and final files will look like.

            //string sFileTemplate = "FinancialYearReport.xlsx";
            string sFileTemplate = "FinancialYearReportTemplate.xltx";
            string sFile = "FinancialYearReportFinal.xlsx";
            if (File.Exists(sFile))
            {
                File.Delete(sFile);
            }

            if (sFileTemplate.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                File.Copy(sFileTemplate, sFile);
            }
            else
            {
                // ends with .xltx
                // Excel template files work differently. You can't work on it
                // directly and then save the result to a different file.
                // More details on this in the accompanying PDF.
                byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(sFileTemplate);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ms.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                    using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
                    {
                        xl.ChangeDocumentType(SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
                        xl.Close();
                    }
                    File.WriteAllBytes(sFile, ms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            try
            {
                BuildWorkbookFromTemplate(sFile);
                Console.WriteLine("Program end");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void BuildWorkbookFromTemplate(string filename)
        {
            string sSheetname = "FYReport";
            // take note that we're opening a file, and not creating a file as before
            using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
            {
                WorkbookPart wbp = xl.WorkbookPart;

                // Get the worksheet with the required name.
                // To be used to match the ID for the required sheet data
                // because the Sheet class and the SheetData class aren't
                // linked to each other directly.
                Sheet s = null;
                if (wbp.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count(nm => nm.Name == sSheetname) == 0)
                {
                    // no such sheet with that name
                    xl.Close();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = (Sheet)wbp.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Where(nm => nm.Name == sSheetname).First();
                }

                WorksheetPart wsp = (WorksheetPart)xl.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(s.Id.Value);
                SheetData sd = (SheetData)wsp.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                // We will update in 2 ways.
                // 1) Get the required cell, do the updates on it, then save the worksheet.
                // 2) Create a Cell with our data, then throw it to the SheetData, then save the worksheet.
                //    If the required cell already exists, we overwrite it. If not, we create it.

                // The difference between the 2 is that, if your worksheet doesn't have the required cell,
                // it becomes more difficult, because you'll have to also append it to the row.
                // More details explained in the accompanying PDF.

                // I left the saving of the worksheet out of the UpdateCell() function
                // because I want to be consistent with the GetCell() version of updating.
                // So wsp.Worksheet.Save(); is done after every cell modification.
                // Otherwise I'd put it at the end of the update function.
                // The code is written for you to understand what's going on, not for optimisation.

                int iPreviousYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
                int iTheYearBeforeThat = iPreviousYear - 1;

                Cell c = null;

                // main title
                c = GetCell(sd, "A", 1);
                if (c != null)
                {
                    if (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                    {
                        c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    }
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue(string.Format("Financial Year Report For {0}/{1}", iTheYearBeforeThat, iPreviousYear));
                    // I was going to show you how to work with an existing value like so:
                    // c.CellValue = new CellValue(string.Format("{0} {1}/{2}", c.CellValue.Text.Trim(), iTheYearBeforeThat, iPreviousYear));
                    // But the existing value is a string, and Excel had kindly saved it into the SharedString table
                    // when I created the template file.
                    // The shared string concept makes things a little more interesting if you really want to work with it.
                    // For now, it's what-you-see-is-what-you-get, which is much simpler.
                    wsp.Worksheet.Save();
                }

                // description of the year before the last
                c = GetCell(sd, "A", 4);
                if (c != null)
                {
                    if (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                    {
                        c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    }
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue(string.Format("Year {0}", iTheYearBeforeThat));
                    wsp.Worksheet.Save();
                }

                // description of last year
                // I'll show you the difference in code for the 2nd method of updating
                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "A13";
                c.CellValue = new CellValue(string.Format("Year {0}", iPreviousYear));
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 13);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                // We will update the revenue and operational costs of "the year before the last" FY.
                // You would probably retrieve the values from a database and fill it here.
                // I don't have any meaningful data anyway, so I'm gonna cheat with a randomiser...
                // I'll use the 2nd method of updating for convenience.
                Random rd = new Random();
                int i;

                for (i = 5; i <= 8; ++i)
                {
                    // revenue values
                    c = new Cell();
                    c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                    c.CellReference = "B" + i.ToString();
                    // range from 8.0 to 12.0
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue((rd.NextDouble() * 4.0 + 8.0).ToString("f2"));
                    UpdateCell(sd, c, (uint)i);
                    wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                    // operational cost values
                    c = new Cell();
                    c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                    c.CellReference = "C" + i.ToString();
                    // range from 0.5 to 1.5
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue((rd.NextDouble() + 0.5).ToString("f2"));
                    UpdateCell(sd, c, (uint)i);
                    wsp.Worksheet.Save();
                }

                // Previous financial year's revenue and operational cost values
                for (i = 14; i <= 17; ++i)
                {
                    // revenue values
                    c = new Cell();
                    c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                    c.CellReference = "B" + i.ToString();
                    // range from 9.0 to 14.0
                    // We've got to have increased revenue, right? :)
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue((rd.NextDouble() * 5.0 + 9.0).ToString("f2"));
                    UpdateCell(sd, c, (uint)i);
                    wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                    // operational cost values
                    c = new Cell();
                    c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                    c.CellReference = "C" + i.ToString();
                    // range from 0.4 to 1.4
                    // We've got to have decreased costs, right? :)
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue((rd.NextDouble() + 0.4).ToString("f2"));
                    UpdateCell(sd, c, (uint)i);
                    wsp.Worksheet.Save();
                }

                // this section is to show you that UpdateCell() works for
                // out of order cells in the same row. Go ahead and mix up
                // the order of the 5 cells (A25, B25, C25, D25 and E25) in
                // the code and check that they are still ordered correctly in the file.
                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "B25";
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("2nd");
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 25u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "E25";
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("5th");
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 25u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "C25";
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("3rd");
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 25u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "A25";
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("1st");
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 25u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "D25";
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("4th");
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 25u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                // Credits!
                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "A27";
                // well, we wouldn't want upper management to think this
                // financial report was *easy* to generate, right? Claim credit!
                c.CellValue = new CellValue("Generated by Vincent");
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 27u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellReference = "E27";
                // you could show upper management that you're working hard,
                // and print a time that's in the wee hours of the morning...
                // But shame on you...
                c.CellValue = new CellValue(string.Format("Generated at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
                UpdateCell(sd, c, 27u);
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                // we have formulae and charts to update in the template
                xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;

                xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                xl.Close();
            }
        }

        private static Cell GetCell(SheetData sd, string ColumnName, UInt32 RowIndex)
        {
            // There's a small chance that the row has no RowIndex assigned.
            // You should know that the property RowIndex is optional.
            // This means the following will fail.
            // But we can't do much about a missing RowIndex in the template.
            Row r = null;
            Cell c = null;
            if (sd.Elements<Row>().Count(ri => ri.RowIndex == RowIndex) > 0)
            {
                r = (Row)sd.Elements<Row>().Where(ri => ri.RowIndex == RowIndex).First();
            }

            if (r != null)
            {
                string sCellReference = ColumnName.ToUpper() + RowIndex.ToString();
                if (r.Elements<Cell>().Count(cr => cr.CellReference.Value == sCellReference) > 0)
                {
                    c = (Cell)r.Elements<Cell>().Where(cr => cr.CellReference.Value == sCellReference).First();
                }
            }

            return c;
        }

        private static void UpdateCell(SheetData sd, Cell CellData, UInt32 RowIndex)
        {
            // There's a small chance that the row has no RowIndex assigned.
            // You should know that the property RowIndex is optional.
            // This means the following will fail.
            // But we can't do much about a missing RowIndex in the template.
            Row r = null;
            if (sd.Elements<Row>().Count(ri => ri.RowIndex == RowIndex) == 0)
            {
                // There's no row at this index, so it also means there's no cell
                // with the data required. So just create the row with the cell.
                r = new Row();
                r.RowIndex = RowIndex;
                r.Append(CellData);
                sd.Append(r);
            }
            else
            {
                r = (Row)sd.Elements<Row>().Where(ri => ri.RowIndex == RowIndex).First();
                // we will assume the cell's CellReference is consistent with the given RowIndex
                if (r.Elements<Cell>().Count(cr => cr.CellReference.Value == CellData.CellReference.Value) > 0)
                {
                    // there's an existing cell
                    Cell c = (Cell)r.Elements<Cell>().Where(cr => cr.CellReference.Value == CellData.CellReference.Value).First();
                    c.DataType = CellData.DataType;
                    // reset to "normal" string value if it's a shared string.
                    // Otherwise, we'll have to go change the value in the SharedStringTable class,
                    // and that's out of scope for now. Let's focus on updating cells, shall we?
                    // We are also assuming we're not stupid enough to set the given cell's
                    // data type to be SharedString...
                    if (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                    {
                        c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    }
                    c.CellValue = new CellValue(CellData.CellValue.Text);

                    // set any other additional properties you want
                }
                else
                {
                    // no such cell

                    IEnumerable<Cell> iec = r.Elements<Cell>();
                    // in case there are no cells in the row
                    if (iec.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        r.Append(CellData);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool bFound = false;
                        // cells need to be in order of their CellReference values
                        foreach (Cell c in iec)
                        {
                            // We assume the existing Cells are already in order.
                            // This means the moment our CellData's CellReference is before
                            // a particular existing Cell's CellReference, we can insert before
                            // that particular existing Cell.
                            if (string.Compare(CellData.CellReference.Value, c.CellReference.Value) < 0)
                            {
                                bFound = true;
                                r.InsertBefore(CellData, c);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        // well, we have to insert our CellData *somewhere*.
                        // If not found in the loop above, then it must have the highest CellReference.
                        // So we just append it at the end of the row.
                        if (!bFound)
                        {
                            r.Append(CellData);
                        }
                    }

                    // we don't append the row to the SheetData variable because
                    // the row already exists. We just need to append the cell.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Vincent's example is using a workbook set up as a template and doesn't cover clearing cells, but he does show how to overwrite cells. To me, it looks like he covers a lot of the things that could go wrong. I would try overwriting cells with nothing first and see if that will work.